# Adding WordNet as a GATE processing resource

Tags: java, text, wordnet, corpus, gate

I am trying to annotate a text corpus with WordNet annotations, using GATE. After adding a WordNet creole plugin into GATE-Developer system, I can only add WordNet as a language resource, but not as a processing resource or application. So I cannot add it to the corpus pipeline.

I will appreciate any help here.

(Yes, I did read the [GATE user manual](http://gate.ac.uk/userguide/).)

Answer (score 0):

You can install wordnet .

I had embedded Wordnet as processing resource in my application .

It solved my problem.

Comment: Could you please share a example code ,embedded gate + Wordnet